# Why after creating a project with "composer create-project" the dependencies are not the latest available versions?

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

For some reason, `composer create-project` command seems to pull stale dependencies versions.

After running `create-project`, if I `chdir` to created folder and run a `composer update`, the newer versions are downloaded.

> aherne@aherne-System-Product-Name:/var/www/html$ **cd framework/**
>   aherne@aherne-System-Product-Name:/var/www/html/framework$ **composer  update** 
>   Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Package operations: 0 installs,
>   12 updates, 0 removals
>     - Updating lucinda/request-validator (v1.0.4 => v1.0.8.1): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/internationalization (v2.0.2 => v2.0.5): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/view-language (v2.1.1 => v2.1.7): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/sql-data-access (v2.0.1 => v2.0.2): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/errors-mvc (v1.1.4 => v1.2.1.1): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/mvc (v2.0.8 => v2.1.3): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/security (v2.0.5 => v2.0.9): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/oauth2-client (v1.6.2 => v1.6.3): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/nosql-data-access (v2.0.3 => v2.0.4): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/logging (v2.0.3 => v2.0.5): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/http-caching (v2.0.1 => v2.0.3.2): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating lucinda/framework-engine (v1.2.5 => v1.3.6): Downloading (100%)          Writing lock file Generating autoload files

Why doesn't `composer create-project` download the latest dependencies versions in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because doing a `create-project` is basically equivalent to cloning the repository and then doing a `composer install`.

And `install` downloads the dependencies declared in the `composer.lock`, which include a specific version declaration. Running `install` is supposed to be safe, and install only the declared dependency versions as explicitly stored in the repository.

`update`, on the other hand, reads the version constraints declared on `composer.json`, downloads the latest available version of each package that fit those constraints, and *then* updates `composer.lock`.

This behaviour is not safe for a brand new installation, because not only your direct dependencies are updated, but also any dependency of a dependency that can be updated will be so, and compatibility problems can be introduced by accident. A lock file in a project represents a *known good* state that can be used to safely install a project working as intended.

References:

- [create-project](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project)
- [install](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i)
- [update](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u)

Comment: Worth noting for OP that `composer.lock` ensures that the versions installed are exactly the same every time and helps ensure that everything works properly. Even though the dependencies are defined in `composer.json` and while update will satisfy those dependencies within the defined bounds, not all developers are 100% reliable in following the SemVer mantra. Long story short: That `composer update` might sneak in a breaking change that you wouldn't otherwise expect.

Comment: Indeed. When I mentioned that `install` is supposed to be “safe”; that was the gist of it. Maybe I should elaborate a bit on the answer using your comment as a template. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed... I committed the lock file:) I know how it works, just forgot it there. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answers, guys! Problem fixed.